# PHP works on Localhost but not on Server

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, forms

I do have some PHP code inside my website which works perfectly on localhost (using XAMPP) but doesn't on my hosting server (Ubuntu 18.04 - php is installed, etc...).

I do call the PHP file using ajax. There you have the code.

HTML:

```
<form id="email-form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="ex: john@gmail.com" name="email" required>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="cta animated-cta" name="submit" value="Continue">
</form>
```

JS:

```
function saveData () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'assets/php/saveData.php',
        data: $('#email').serialize()
    });
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    $data = $_POST['email']  . PHP_EOL;
    $file = fopen('../diverse/emails.csv', $data);
    fwrite($file, $data);
    fclose($file);
?>
```

I guess there's a problem with the code (but can't find it). The weird part is that it works fine on localhost but not on server, which has PHP installed and executes my PHP page. I did try on 2 different hosting servers but it's the same story.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: do you get any error ? is your server PHP config same as your localhost PHP config ?

Comment: The second argument to `fopen()` should be a mode like `r` or `w`. Why are you using `$data` there?

Comment: You can replace the entire thing with `file_put_contents("../diverse/emails.csv", $data);`

Comment: @Barmar Oh, this was the problem... Solved. :) And put 'a' in fopen. Because with 'w', couldn't store more than 1 line, don't know why.. :)

Comment: @Barmar Thank you so much!

Comment: Because `w` means to overwrite, `a` means to append. You can use the `FILE_APPEND` option in `file_put_contents()` to get the same result.